# jQuery expandable and collapsible divs

Tags: jquery

I have a small problem with some expanding and collapsing divs on a FAQs page I am creating. When the user clicks a question it needs to collapse all other answer divs and expand only the answer to the clicked (question) div. I now have it figured out - EXCEPT once the user has clicked all the divs on the page and they have all expanded and then collapsed afterwards, it then takes 2 mouse clicks to reopen them again instead of just one.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.answer').hide(); // hide the answer divs first

$('#content .question').click().toggle(
    function() {
         $('.answer').hide(); //hide all other divs when clicked
         $('#content .question').removeClass('close'); // as well as remove the 'expanded' icon
         $(this).next('.answer').slideDown();  //slidedown the appropriate div
         $(this).addClass('close'); //as well as insert the 'expanded' icon
         },
         function() {
            $(this).next('.answer').slideUp(); // hide the selected div
            $(this).removeClass('close'); // as well as remove the 'expanded' icon
            }
        );
    });
```

CSS:

```
#content {width: 1310px; height: 350px;}
#col_1 {width: 380px; height: 350px; margin: 20px; padding: 5px;}
.question {color: #64AA01; background-image:  url(images/open_div.jpg); cursor: pointer; background-repeat: no-repeat; padding-left: 15px;}
.close {background-image:  url(images/close_div.jpg);}
.answer {margin-left: 16px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">

<div id="col_1">

<div class="question">
<div align="justify">Q: This is question 1.</div>
</div>

<div class="answer" style = "width: 360px;">
<div align="justify">A: This answer is the answer to question 1.</div>
</div><br><br>

<div class="question">Q: This is question 2.</div>
<div class="answer" style = "width: 360px;">
<div align="justify">A: This answer is the answer to question 2.</div>
</div><br><br>

<div class="question">
<div align="justify">Q: This is question 3.</div>
</div>

<div class="answer" style = "width: 360px;">
<div align="justify">A: This answer is the answer to question 3.</div>
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It might be worth looking at jQuery-ui and the accordion feature.  It has everything you are describing: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XUGA4zibUynvLqq5njuP?p=preview) example.

You don't need to use toggle in this case:

```
 $('#content .question').click(function() {
     $('#content .question').removeClass('close'); // as well as remove the 'expanded' icon
     $('#content .answer').slideUp();
     $(this).next('.answer').slideDown(); //slidedown the appropriate div
     $(this).addClass('close'); //as well as insert the 'expanded' icon
    });
  });
```

Also, I added this to the css so that your answers default to not show:

```
.answer {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your prompt answers, they were all good answers, I have chosen Lerevemes answer as the one that most suits my needs - it works great now. Thanks to everyone else also!

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FF8WM/3/)</kbd>

```
$('.answer').hide(); // hide the answer divs first

$('.question').click(function() {
    $('.answer').slideUp();
    $(this).next('.answer').slideDown();
});
```

---

Here is a modification that allows you to click anywhere outside of the questions and all answers will be re-closed. Note the use of `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent answers from *always* being re-hidden.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/FF8WM/2/)</kbd>

```
$('.answer').hide(); // hide the answer divs first

$('.question').click(function(e) {
    $('.answer').slideUp();
    $(this).next('.answer').slideDown();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(){
    $('.answer').slideUp();
});
```